# How to union all geometry of selection in one shape with PostgreSQL?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, postgresql

I’m using PostgreSQL with ArcGIS functions. So I trying to union all geometry of selection in one variable with sde.st_union geometry function. Then I want to insert it to another table with scene_id and shape. I use LOOP and temp variable (st_geometry type).[image]

Comment: Where is your insert statement. ST_Union on it's own will give you nothing. You need Insert into ... (scene_id, shape) select scene_id, st_union(....) type syntax.

Comment: I just show the example without insertion statement. Could you explain how to union all rows in selection? st_union does not work this way. As far as I know, st_union function do not unions all raws in selection at once. I have to iterate through the geometry of each row and union it with each other or accumulate it in one geometry type variable as I tried to do above.

Comment: It does, you can do ST_Union(geom) and it will union all the rows that match a condition.

Comment: St union of postgis library does but i use arcgis st_geometry type so o need st_geometry function

Comment: *i need sde.st_union function which does not  do it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sde.st_astext(sde.st_geomcollfromwkb(public.st_asewkb(public.st_union(public.ST_GeomFromWKB(sde.st_asbinary(shape)))))) as union_area
FROM sat_scene
WHERE "some condition"
```